# Why my ANN is not learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm doing electricity load forecasting using a simple feedforward neural network. Following is my code:

```
...

num_periods = 24
f_horizon = 48  #forecast horizon

...

#RNN designning
tf.reset_default_graph()

inputs = num_periods    #input vector size
hidden = 100    
output = num_periods    #output vector size
learning_rate = 0.01
seed = 128

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output])

weights = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([inputs, hidden], seed=seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden, output], seed=seed))
}

biases = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,hidden], seed=seed)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,output], seed=seed))
}

hidden_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['hidden']), biases['hidden'])
hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer)

output_layer = tf.matmul(hidden_layer, weights['output']) + biases['output']

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = output_layer, labels = y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()           #initialize all the variables
epochs = 1000     #number of iterations or training cycles, includes both the FeedFoward and Backpropogation
mape = []

...

for st in state.values():
        print("State: ", st, end='\n')
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init.run()
            for ep in range(epochs):
                sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: x_batches[st], y: y_batches[st]})
        print("\n")
```

Here is what I'm getting the output for the `NSW` state:
[image: cost1]
[image: cost2]

As we can see that the cost is increasing continuously with epochs. Why is this happening ?

Comment: What does your data look like ? Is it multi-class classification ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan My data is time series. I have made batches like this:
`x_data_nsw = TS_NSW[:(len(TS_NSW) - f_horizon -((len(TS_NSW)-f_horizon) % num_periods))] ` and
`x_batches = {'NSW': x_data_nsw.reshape(-1, num_periods),}`
Similarly `y_batches` etc.

Comment: Timeseries forecasting is usually done using an LSTM.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Yes you are right. But I was testing some algorithms for weight and bias initialization.

Comment: Seems you are performing regression, while the loss you use is for classification.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thanks for pointing that out. It's working now.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro But can you tell me why the loss went increasing linearly with cross_entropy and softmax whereas with Mean Square Error it worked as required ?

Comment: No, nobody can tell you why a plot has that shape without extensive experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong loss, as forecasting electricity load sounds like a regression problem, while cross entropy is only for classification.

Something like mean squared error should work instead.